# How connect two pc over two different wifi with java socket?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, wifi

I have created a server in Java with socket and a client that connects to the server. This works between two pc on the same wifi, how can i make it work on two different wifi (two pc in two different houses)?
P.S. sorry my bad english.

Comment: Get public IP address.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make your server available **publicly** to be able to make connection from other client (connected from some other wifi network)

One possible solution is to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which will make it possible to map your local server to publicly accessible url. This server is **absolutely** **free** to use and I have personally used it multiple times for publicly exposing my local servers.

**Edit 1** -

Let say your socket server is running on port 6666, you need to run following command -

```
./ngrok tcp 6666
```

this will result in following response

```
Session Status                online                                                                                                                        
Account                       ********@gmail.com (Plan: Free)                                                                                              
Version                       2.3.35                                                                                                                        
Region                        United States (us)                                                                                                            
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                                         
Forwarding                    tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:15341 -> localhost:6666                                                                                  

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                                                   
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

after this, you will be able to connect you server using following command from other java client -

```
socket = new Socket("0.tcp.ngrok.io", 15341);
```

Comment: sorry i need help, i downloaded ngrok and i launched it with CMD, with the command ngrok http, on the port 80 and i activated apache from XAMPP, but i don't know how to use ngrok on the java program, for the connection i use  Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",port); in the java program i use 6789 port, i tried to write abcdef.ngrok.io instead of localhost but the connection failed, after i tried to replace 80 to 6789 but the server ends as soon as i launch it. Any suggestions?

Comment: you will need to map **TCP protocol** for socket connections, for your use-case it will look like **./ngrok tcp 6789**, after that it will give you something like **tcp://url:port** . use this **url** and **port** instead of localhost and your port. I tested it and I was able to connect it using **new Socket("0.tcp.ngrok.io", 16261)** , where **0.tcp.ngrok.io** and **16261** are the url and port provided by ngrok. Please test and let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: thanks a lot i think it works, i tried on the same wifi and it works, as soon as i have the chance i will try on two different wifi and i will let you know, again thanks without you it would have taken me months to resolve this situation